# Installing Node.js with homebrew issue

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I'm trying to install Node.js with homebrew on OS X but I'm running into a few issues and I'm not quite sure how to fix them. When I run `brew doctor` I get the following output:

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    node

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
    cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
Error: Homebrew doesn't know what compiler versions ship with your version
of Xcode (5.1). Please `brew update` and if that doesn't help, file
an issue with the output of `brew --config`:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues

Note that we only track stable, released versions of Xcode.

Thanks!
```

I tried to run `brew link node` and got the following message:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26... Warning: Could not link node. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/dtrace/node.d
Target /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

So then I tried to run `brew link --overwrite node` and got the following error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26... Warning: Could not link node. Unlinking...

Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
```

I am now stuck and not really sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I got this issue solved by running:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the permission issue try

```
sudo brew link --overwrite node
```

Note that unless you have specific reasons to install node using homebrew, I would recommend to just go to http://nodejs.org/, download the Mac OS installer and let it do everything for you.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It returned this type of error: "Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link` You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root. However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at your own risk." I guess brew for me isn't owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party but I'm having the same issue- I think I'm onto something though.

Check your permissions on /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d by running `ls -al /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d`. If the owner is someone other than your username, fix that by running

```
sudo chown -R $USER:staff /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
```

This should give you the permissions you need to proceed. After that, I hit a few more directories that had owners listed as `nobody` (I actually ended up chowning all of /usr/local/Cellar, I'll wait for comments to see how bad of an idea that was).